# Symbolicate iPhone crash report without .dSYM files

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Is there a way to symbolicate iPhone crash report without .dSYM files?

I did keep the original binary (.app) that I submitted to the App Store, but I didn't keep .dSYM file. And I have changed the source code a lot after submitting. The crash reports from my users are kind of useless right now.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is NO. I recommend you to use "build & archive" feature which can be found in Organizer. It will store everything needed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can generate dSYM files using dsymutil from the binary, never tried, but makes sense since binary *does contain* symbol table. But you should not expect to get source code line numbers I presume. [Look there for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments).