# Apple Instruments - Counters - Source unavailable

Tags: instruments, performancecounter, xcode-instruments

I've been running into a problem with Apple Instruments (4.6, Xcode 4.6.2 on 10.8.3).
Normally when using the Time Profiler, I can look at my source and see the hotspots without any problems (same project).

This time I've been trying to use the "Counters" Template to sample my CPUs Performance Counter Events. It samples the events as it should and I also have the same time based profiling information as well, however when I try to step into my code to look at the hot spots, like I can do for the "Time Profiler", all I get is "Unavailable" where I used to have the source. No Assembly either.

The Project is built as:

- Release build
- Debugging information is on and not stripped
- DWARF + dsym is used to store the profiling data.

As I said, its the same configuration that works for the time profiler.
I already tried to (pretty much all that's stated in here: [Xcode 4 Instruments doesn't show source lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268041/xcode-4-instruments-doesnt-show-source-lines) , except for doing -O0, debug performance is not of interest to me)

- recompile
- relocate the dysm file using "File -> Re-Symbolicate"

As soon as I plainly close Instruments, start another Profile from Xcode and choose the Time Profiler, it works, if I go back to the Performance Counters, it stops.

Is this the default behaviour? Should it be like this? Has anybody already managed to get it working, in the current Instruments version? Otherwise it might be worth to file a bug with Apple.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Xcode 5.1 beta4. For me its fixed there: Counter works now.

The seed notes mentions some details what they did. Don't know if its under NDA.