# "Show Obj-c Only" flag hides all the content of call tree on xCode Instruments

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, instruments

I'm following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) tutorial about Instruments. The tutorial provides a sample project to test the steps described on it.

The problem is that, when I check "Show Obj-c Only" and "Hide System Libraries" flags, all the lines in call tree list is hidden, but the code in the project is written in Obj-C. Is there something I have to change in the configuration to see the project lines as in the tutorial?

Call tree list image taken from the tutorial showing how it must to be:
[image: Call tree list image taken from the tutorial showing how it must to be]

Screenshot of my instruments execution:
[image: Screenshot of my instruments execution]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don`t really know what happens here, but now it works. How?

What I did:

- Erase the app in the device
- Kill xCode ( using activity monitor )
- Restart the computer ( Only restarting xcode didn't work )
- Restart the device.
- Clean the project
- Try again.

May be is not the best answer, but it worked for me.

[UPDATE] The issue is there again, so I try this: [Xcode 4 Instruments doesn't show source lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268041/xcode-4-instruments-doesnt-show-source-lines)

And it works!