# Instruments, CPU time profiling, does't show Obj-C calls

Tags: objective-c, cpu, profile, instruments

I'm trying to profile my code and use Instruments (iOS->CPU->Time Profiler) for it. I choose application and run the test. In Call Tree options I select 'Show Obj-C Only' check box but I don't see my application calls, just system/sdk libraries internal calls.
The program built in debug mode.

How can I see my application's call?

Comment: This helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments

Answer (score 4):

you are profiling with the release configuration, but that one does not have hte debug symbols. Edit the target scheme and pick the debug