# Missing symbol names when profiling iPhone app in Instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, profiling, instruments

I don't get any symbol names when I'm profiling my iPhone app.

It works in the simulator and when using Debug mode on the device, but not when using Release (as you should use when profiling). I know the dsym-file is generated for both release and debug, so that is not the problem.

I've tried the solution described here:

[Missing symbol names when profiling IPhone application with Instruments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments)

But **when i choose "Re-Symbolicate Document" my app's name doesn't appear in the binary list** (it does appear when using debug), so I can't try to manually add the dsym file.

I've also tried:

- Adding and removing my Derived Data folder from Spotlight's Privacy list
- Removing the app from the iPhone
- Clean & Build before profiling
- Removing the Derived Data folder before building and profiling

What can be the problem?

Comment: I just have the same problem here. Any suggestion? Did you manage to find a solution/workaround

Comment: No, haven't found a solution :( please let me know if you run in to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

today i also missing symbols when profile on iPhone.
but i ever missing to find dsym file when i build a platform to analyse the crash reports. i remember i fix it by reindex spotlight.

so this time i do it to, because i find in resymbolicate documents, the instruments cannot find the dsym file for specfic udid. so i guess it is caused by system failed to find it with the help of spotlight(system always use mdfind command to find dsym file). if the spotlight failed to find, maybe the instrument cannot find dsym file too ..

so i go search the reindexing command:
sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD

-E will tell the system to reindexing 
this command to reindex the root disk. so it may costs some time.

after reindex, it's better for you to give a path to resymbolicate.

it's ok for me to make it work, if you have something don't understand, please let me known. thanks.