# instruments on iOS device-- unable to symbolicate because app not appearing in the drop-down

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, symbolicate

I ran the time profiler on the device.  I ended up with a trace, but no symbols.  So, following the suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments), I attempted to re-symbolicate.  However, the drop-down list of binaries was empty.  See the screen shot.  How can I get symbols into my trace?

For general instructions on symbolicating profiler runs, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments).  But this particular problem is not addressed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the dSYM and the app bundle, you can use this Symbolication tool I wrote to quickly Symbolicate your app's addresses.

```
symbolication your.app.dSYM your.app.trace
```

The symbolicated version will be printed to STDOUT. For best results, keep your .app in the same folder as your .dSYM.

https://github.com/Imperiopolis/Symbolication

You could also manually Symbolicate just the problem line using GDB. Open your dSYM with GDB, then run

```
set print symbol-filename on
p/a address
```

Comment: Thanks - your tool's output clued me into putting the .app and .dSYM together. Boom, symbolication magically works again system-wide. Xcode's archives do not have this layout, yet symbolication works _if  Xcode knows about the archive_, otherwise tough luck. I don't get why this process is so fragile and so averse to explicitly passing the app and dSYM.

Comment: No, my mistake - Xcode did know about the archive. Maybe it was confused by the presence of another identical copy elsewhere. Still would be nice to be able to explicitly symbolicate for when the automagic way fails.