# How to export symbols for Frameworks developed as private pod / Instruments not displaying symbols for private pod framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, instruments

**tldr**; I'm trying to profile my application using Time Profiller however the symbols for my internally developed framework (added to the app as a private Cocoapods) are missing, what can I do to resolve this?

[image]
I've looked over a few forums, and all I can see is to set Debug Information to "DWARF with dSYM file" which I have set on both the main project, and the framework.

Is there a flag I can set, somewhere, even if it' overwriting something in the Cocoapods.sh files that would allow the generation of dSYM in for my embedded framework.

FYI I've also posted this on https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6572

Thanks.

Using CocoaPods 1.2.0
Xcode 8.2.1
Swift 2.3

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776466/missing-symbol-names-when-profiling-iphone-application-with-instruments . If you have dsym file, you can use it in instruments.

Comment: @batu yes I've read this already. However now realising that our project had it's Profiling configuration set as the Debug configuration, and not the Release Configuration. It's now generating dSYMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out that my build configuration for the Profiling schema was set to the Debug configuration and not the Release configuration.

Hopefully that helps someone else in the future.